# Staticfile на production сервере

Tags: django

При разработке как обычно все разворачивается на тестовом сервере, или локально. Использую встроенные `staticfile`.
Однако когда переношу на рабочий сервер, и меняю `DEBUG = False`, то сервер падает. Хотя статика отдается уже с помощью `nginx`.

Подскажите, что нужно поменять, чтобы `Django` пропускало шаг отдачи статики? Уже пробовал в `settings` отключать разные элементы настройки статики, не помогало ничего, при `DEBUG = False` все вылетает.

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что именно падает, и как. URL и root для статики на продакшен верно настроены (то, что реально отдает файлы nginx, не убирает необходимости настройки)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При неверной настройке статики сервер падать не должен, просто будет отдаваться страница с голым HTML. Такое поведение может быть симптомом того, что Вы не указали `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['your-domain.ru']` в settings.py. Посмотрите, может Django в логах или Вам на почту об этом написал.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно в этом была проблема. Вот тут описана подробнее моя проблема и решение, если кому-то будет полезно http://getluky.net/2013/02/21/django-debugfalse-and-allowed_hosts/.